# Cannot fit data

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

First up, I'm quite new to Mathematica so any hints on better code would be greatly appreciated. I have already asked the question connected to this code, but later I've found a mistake. Now I need to fit my data. I have two sets of data: one for positive value of `F` -`ArrayFVelp` and another for negative value of `F` -`ArrayFVelm`. I have a fitting function `newModel`, and I would like to know the parameters `m, A, G` of the model. I've  tried to use NonLinearModelFit, FindFit, and Method -> "NMinimize", but all my attempts were unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

```
ArrayFVelp ={{2.57701, 22.7458}, {3.83219, 29.6856}, {5.30692, 36.3019}, {6.93287,
   41.1253}, {8.31929, 35.6894}, {9.31232, 35.5811}};

ArrayFVelm = {{1.04636, 17.0544}, {1.69469, 79.1147}, {2.17592, 129.16}, {2.17978, 
  173.519}};

L = 4.0*^-3;
kT = 1.38*^-5*300;
diff = 30.0;

newModel[m_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, G_?NumericQ, F_?NumericQ] := (
   f := G*Exp[A (1 - 1/(1 - #^2))] &;
   g := 2 ((# + L/2)/(L/2*2))^(-(Log[2]/Log[1/2 + m/2])) - 1 &;
   well := f[g[#], m, A, G] &;

   V := Piecewise[{{well[#, m, A, 
         G], # >= -L/2 && # <= L/2}, {well[# - L, m, A, 
         G], # > L/2 && # <= L/2 + L}}] &;
   n = diff/
     NIntegrate[(Exp[V[y] - F*y/kT]*Exp[F*x/kT - V[x]]) // 
       Evaluate, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, x, x + L}, WorkingPrecision -> 5];
   Abs[L*n*(1 - Exp[-F*L/kT])]
   );
fit := FindFit[
  ArrayFVelm, {newModel[m, A, G, F], -1 < m < 0, 
   0 <= A <= 32, -15 <= G <= -0}, {m, A, G}, F]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unsuccessful"?  Were there error messages?

Comment: Try `fit=` instead of `fit:=`

Comment: The size of data 6 is too small for a reliable fit.

Comment: @Roman I've tried it yet, no result.

Comment: @user64494 Unfortunately, this is all my data for fitting

Comment: @JimB Here it is NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral.                     General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::errprec will be suppressed during this calculation. NIntegrate:: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more \
than 2000 times.

Comment: @JimB I've added pictures of errors

Comment: Your `WorkingPrecision` setting is not productive. You probably want `PrecisionGoal->5`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I got the same errors about integration converging too slowly.

Comment: `WorkingPrecision->5` is useful only for educational / didactic purposes, not for real computations.